# How to filter the first Ip from a 5 tuple that is present in every line in Linux

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I would like to filter the first IP from the given output below.

```
3676798  I/H      628   71.1.219.106                            10198     71.1.208.58                             20198       UDP       A
3676798  R/U      628   71.1.208.58                             20198     71.1.219.106                            10198       UDP       A
3676799  I/H      1066  71.1.57.57                              10008     71.1.57.53                              20008       UDP       A
3676799  R/U      1066  71.1.57.53                              20008     71.1.57.57                              10008       UDP       A
3676800  I/H      532   71.1.213.104                            10142     71.1.203.52                             20142       UDP       A
3676800  R/U      532   71.1.203.52                             20142     71.1.213.104                            10142       UDP       A
```

Using the below command, I'm able to get all the IP's but I would like to get only the first ip from each line which has 2 IP's. There may be line which might not have IP's at all. so I would like to ignore that line.

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' <filename>
```

I tried to use Awk to get it (as suggested in one of the comments) but this was unsuccessful since it prints the fourth field from any line which does not have IP's as well.

```
awk '{ print $4 }' file
```

Any pointers would be highly helpful.

Comment: If the file is consistently formatted like this, `awk '{ print $4; exit }' file`

Comment: I tried to use ` awk '{ print $4}' file` but it prints the 4th word from the line which does not match ip address format. as an example, i have the following line in my file "No. of flows: 13222 " and the awk output prints 13222 as well.

Comment: That does not match the example in your question at all. If the file has the IP address in a predictable column, the same approach should work, just change the column. But I posted other solutions in the earlier comment, too.

Comment: I tried the `grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' file1  | head -n 1
71.1.95.51
grep: write error: Broken pipe` and it gives the output from one line only.. but i want the output from multiple lines. I tried wtih `grep -m1` option as well and that also gives only one line of output

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. Each line will have 2 IP's . some line might not have IP's as well. I want to get the first ip from each line which has 2 IP's .. Thats the requirement. I will try the perl command once.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question. My Perl comment had a couple of typos but I posted an answer with a fixed version. Going forward, please take care to include example data which properly represents the problem you are trying to solve (in this case, include lines with no IP address and explain how those should be handled); see also the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Please don't use the word `filter` in this context as it's ambiguous and could mean only select that thing for output or remove that thing from the output. If you're filtering water when making coffee you want what comes out of the filter, but if you're filtering water when panning for gold you want what's held back by the filter. Same for strings when "filtering" text - just say `print`, or `delete`, whichever it is you mean. Adding the expected output would clarify which you want.

Comment: Regarding `prints the fourth field from any line which does not have IP's as well.` - all of your posted sample input has IPs in the fourth field. If that's not what your real data looks like then don't post that as the sample data for us to test with. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with truly representative sample input and expected output that we can copy/paste to test a potential solution with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only print when the fourth field matches an IP address,

```
awk '$4 ~ /^[1-9][0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}$/{ print $4 }' file
```

To only print the first IP address on any line, regardless of where exactly it's found, try Perl:

```
perl -ne 's/.*?([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}).*/$1/ and print' file
```

This looks quite similar to `sed` but the non-greedy `.*?` is not available in `sed`.  If you wanted the *last* IP address on every line, it would be easy to do with `sed`.