# How to literally match the Curly braces in python regular expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to filter an ip address from a file stored at a remote server. As per the guidence received in the thread , [How to filter the first Ip from a 5 tuple that is present in every line in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73490921/) , i was able to filter the IP address on the remote server using the below regex match.

```
cat <file name> | grep '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' | awk '{print $4}'
```

Now i try to pass on the same command to a python script and thats where i;m getting the following error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_flow_diff.py", line 410, in <module>
    getSIPsFromFile(log, vsx_pri_hdl, 'primary')
  File "get_flow_diff.py", line 269, in getSIPsFromFile
    cmd = 'cat {0} | grep \'[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\' | awk \'{print $4}'.format(file_name)
KeyError: '1,3\\'
```

looks like python is interpreting as a dict since it has curly braces.I tried to precede with backslash but looks like this does not help.

could someone help me to solve this problem

I tried to google it but could not find a working solution.

Thanks.

Comment: The way you get an actual curly bracket in a string that will have `.format()` applied to it is to double it - `{{` instead of just `{`.  A backslash would escape the curly brace in the context of a Python regular expression, but you aren't dealing with Python regular expressions here.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment but less rep :|, anyways try using triple quotes or double quotes as your command prompt script.

For example:

`cmd = '''cat {0} | grep \'[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\' | awk \'{print $4}'''`

`cmd = "cat {0} | grep \'[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\' | awk \'{print $4}"`

Hopefully this works

Comment: when we use format to substitute the file name, i get the same error..               
`>>> cmd = '''cat {0} | grep \'[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\' | awk \'{print $4}'''.format(file_name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '1,3\\'
>>> `